# Will Windows 10 become unbootable if I add a dedicated GPU?

Tags: windows-10, boot, gpu

My computer's specifications:

```
CPU:        Intel Core i5-4430 @ 3.00GHz
GPU:        Intel HD Graphics 4600
Mainboard:  BIOSTAR H81MHV3
RAM:        DDR3 1600MHz 4GB + 8GB
HDD:        Seagate SATA HDD 500GB + 1TB + 2TB
```

I am planning to buy an NVIDIA dedicated graphics card with 2GB VRAM, however I don't know if the current Windows 10 installation will be unbootable, requiring a clean install.

- I ask because after replacing the mainboard and CPU following the previous mainboard's death, I reinstalled Windows when it wouldn't boot and returned BSOD error:

  ```
  A required device isn't connected or can't be accessed.
  ```

Do I need to perform a clean install after the hardware change?

Comment: General FYI: your previous issue could have been solved by booting to WinRE - you did not need to reinstall Windows _(Windows 10 will auto-boot to WinRE if the bootloader twice fails to load Windows)_. If WinRE's Startup Repair could not have solved in, `bootrec` likely would have. Did you try googling the error by chance, as that would have shown similar advice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your previous problems have no relation to your current situation.
When you changed the motherboard you changed the motherboard chipset as well. That basically changed almost all the hardware at the same time.
If too much changes simultaneously, especially chipset, Windows often can't cope with that.

Just changing the video-card is not a biggy. Windows can still boot just fine as that doesn't affect the motherboard chipset and drivers. And after the base system is booted it can start to figure out what drivers it needs for the new video-card.

Please note that Windows 10 has build-in drivers for most NVidia cards, but to get more features and better gaming performance you will have to download and install the NVidia drivers. Usually it is best to get the latest drivers directly from NVidia. Drivers that came with the card or are available from the card manufacturer web-site are often out-dated and sometimes also include bloatware that you don't really need.

Comment: Windows Update will auto-update all drivers _(excl. CPU-related drivers)_ with the OEM's WHQL drivers available on their site - there's no need to install them separately, simply run Windows Update. _(Also, changing out a motherboard does not require reinstalling Windows, simply booting to WinRE would have resolved the issue, either via Startup Repair or `bootrec`. One of the few exceptions to this is if the motherboard requires specific drivers to boot from NVME SSDs, but the Chipset drivers have nothing to do with booting Windows - if they did, WinPE couldn't be booted to install Windows.)_

Comment: @JW0914 The WHQL drivers for several older NVidia cards haven't been updated in years (designed for the initial 2015 release of Windows 10). But there are much newer non-WHQL drivers available directly form NVidia that perform better and are more stable, with later W10 releases. Especially in combination with the Intel GPU integrated in the CPU.

Comment: Windows 10 should list non-WHQL drivers as optional updates in _Settings_ → _Update & Security_ → _View optional updates_ → _Driver updates_

Comment: The only advice would be to wipe the current Nvidia drivers, if they are several years older, if you are getting any a Nvidia GPU within the last 2 generations.  This will force Windows to install the Microsoft Basic Display driver, and allow you to install the current driver, once the card is installed.  Additionally, you should have the driver offline, so it can easily be installed.